# Is accessing unix filesystems from windows ontopic?

Tags: discussion, scope

How much Windows is ontopic? we decided a while ago that cygwin is ontopic because there isn't usually much difference. But is [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13693/29) about reading Linux filesystems from a windows system ontopic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was surprised to see indecision; in my mind this is clearly off-topic. It's a [software-rec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) for a Windows program; the fact that the Windows program will be interacting with Linux data doesn't really matter to me. I won't close it since mattdm was of the opposite opinion, but call it a vote to close for me

Comment: Seconded. At work, I'm often the go-to guy for Linux, and people might ask me how to read NTFS on Linux. There's a colleague who's the go-to guy for Windows, and people might ask him how to read ext2 on Windows. So the question belongs on a Windows site.

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to be inclusive; it *is* about Linux-standard filesystems, after all. It's likely that Linux/Unix experts who have worked in a heterogeneous environment are the best-suited to give a good answer.

Comment: but isn't superuser and serverfault more the site's for "heterogeneous" environments?

Comment: Well, the first part is the important thing to me — it is about Linux filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally torn on this I can actually see this being interesting to Unix and Linux people, but the fact remains outside of these being Linux filesystems I don't see that this has anything to do with Linux or Unix.

I think if I could vote on the question without it it immediately closing it, I'd vote to close it as offtopic.